# Rendering to framebuffer only renders bottom left of my scene

Tags: c++, opengl

[image]

When I render the same scene with a framebuffer smaller than my window size I only get the very bottom left of the scene, I would expect to see the center. Both scenes are rendered exactly the same way with the camera in the exact same place.

Any ideas on what could cause the framebuffer to only render the bottom left of the scene? It seems like something needs to be scaled down.

Here is the relevant code, let me know if you want me to include anything else. I'm pretty confident the code that draws the texture on the screen is correct, it doesn't do any scaling or translating.

The quad I am using to draw the framebuffer. The coordinates are x,y,z then texture coordinates.

```
float texture_test[] = {
    -0.5, -0.5, 0,      0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5, -0.5, 0,       1.0, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0,        1.0, 1.0,

    -0.5, -0.5, 0,      0.0, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0,        1.0, 1.0,
    -0.5, 0.5, 0,       0.0, 1.0

};
```

The initialization code:

```
int WIDTH = 1440;
int HEIGHT = 900;


// Create FBO
unsigned int fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);


// Create texture
unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// ---- If I change WIDTH/10 to WIDTH and HEIGHT/10 to HEIGHT the center of the textured scene is now correct. 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, WIDTH/10 , HEIGHT/10, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


// Attaches the texture to the framebuffer
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);


unsigned int rbo;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, WIDTH/10, HEIGHT/10 );

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);


assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

The main loop:

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgram.program_id);


// this sets uniforms for the view matrix, perspective matrix, and camera position
glw_update_camera(&shaderProgram, &cam);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// this binds vertex array to the cube vertex, then set uniforms for model matrix and color then calls glDrawArrays thousands of times
draw_cubes(&shaderProgram, &main_chunk, &player, &raycast_result);


glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// now do exact same thing for the main screen NO STATE HAS BEEN MODIFIED!!!
draw_cubes(&shaderProgram, &main_chunk, &player, &raycast_result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the camera matrix, one also has to define the viewport mapping (from NDC to pixel coordinates) by calling [`glViewport`]/https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml(.

In your case, you have to make sure that this viewport mapping maps the center of the camera area to the framebuffer while still maintaining the same scale. This can be done, for example, with the following code:

```
int window_viewport_width, window_viewport_height;
int x = -(window_viewport_width - framebuffer_width )/ 2;
int y = -(window_viewport_height - framebuffer_height) / 2;

glViewport(x,y, window_viewport_width, window_viewport_height);
```

This code has to be called before rendering to the framebuffer. Also don't forget to reset it before rendering to the window:

```
//Bind framebuffer
glViewport(x, y, window_viewport_width, window_viewport_height);
glDraw*();

//Unbind framebuffer
glViewport(0, 0, window_viewport_width, window_viewport_height);
glDraw*();
```

If you meant by "see the center" that you want to see the full scene, then use the following mapping

```
glViewport(0, 0, framebuffer_width, framebuffer_height);
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it but I didn't need to do the x and y calculation you did, adding `glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH / 10, HEIGHT / 10);` right before I rendered the framebuffer and resetting it right before I rendered to the screen seemed to fix it. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: What you use seems to scale down the scene rendered to the viewport. You'd said that you want to see the center. If you want to see the full scene in the framebuffer, then use (0,0,framebuffer_width, framebuffer_height).